# I am working on a project and I want to popolated some data on postman but there are two issues

Tags: node.js, http-headers, typeerror

res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED)

and this error is loggeg
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CREATED')

but res.status(201) works fine

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found out the issue.

I put:

```js
const { StatusCodes } = ('http-status-codes');
```

Instead of:

```js
const { StatusCodes } = require('http-status-codes');
```

Working fine now.